# How do I keep delimiter in re.split on same index of returned list

Tags: python, regex

When using `re.split()` I know how to keep delimiter in split results, is to use `()` capturing groups.

But I have an issue, here is my Regex `(<br>*\s*[a-z]+)` and here is string

```
Attribute Information:</b><br>Listing of attributes:<br>&gt;50K, <br>age: continuous.<br>workclass: Private, Self-emp-not-inc, Self-emp-inc, Federal-gov, Local-gov, State-gov, Without-pay, Never-worked.<br>fnlwgt: continuous.
```

The returned results from split are

```
[u'<br>age', u': continuous.\r', u'<br>workclass', u': Private, Self-emp-not-inc, Self-emp-inc, Federal-gov, Local-gov, State-gov, Without-pay, Never-worked.\r', u'<br>fnlwgt',   u': continuous.\r']
```

Means both of these are on different indexes `[u'<br>age', u': continuous.\r']`

I want them to be on same index `[u'<br>age: continuous.\r'`

**Edit**

Actually I am scraping this part 
[image]
from this URL http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult
And I want to get `age: continuous.` and `fnlwgt: continuous.` and all of them in separate element inside a list

Comment: Could you explain the requirements? Also, you have `\r` in the sample output, but there are no linebreaks in the sample input you shared.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew see edits

Comment: Why not split the whole `p` tag value with `<br>` to get separate lines? Or, I guess you are after `r'<br>(?=\s*[a-z-]+:)'`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xhxont/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ah yes the regex you posted is what I wanted ... really good ... can you post an answer on why you kept `<br>` outside of `()` ... I mean explain your regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to split on a `<br>` that is followed with 0+ whitespaces and 1+ letters or hyphens.

You need to turn a part of your pattern into a *non-consuming* subpattern, a *positive lookahead*:

```
r'<br>(?=\s*[A-Za-z-]+:)'
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xhxont/3)

A `(?=\s*[a-zA-Z-]+:)`, being a [zero-width assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), does not consume (=place text into the match) the substring after `<br>` that meets the `\s*[a-z-]+:` pattern, but requires it to appear there.

Comment: Can you make a change to look both `1+ lowercase or uppercase letters`

Comment: I updated the answer. Actually, you can use a `re.I` flag and go on using `[a-z-]`

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally use the following positive regex:

```
(?<=<br>).*?:.*
```

You can see it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/z7N3oW/1). In order to extract all the matches use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall).